# Sharepoint 2013 : how to add a custom themable css ? (file not found)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, theme, cssregistration

Sharepoint looks for my css in

/sites/mysite/_catalogs/theme/Themed/549F7A23/foo-6358CA7D.themedcss?ctag=2

when it is in

/sites/mysite/Style Library/fr-fr/themable/foo.css 
(I can reach it via http)

-- what I did --

I created my style foo.css in  "Style Library/fr-fr/themable/" (and duplicated it in en-us too)

I created a custom "master" (or rather a custom html linked to a master)
where I added the following

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/fr-fr/Themable/foo.css %&gt;" EnableCssTheming="true" runat="server"/>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="15">-->
            <!--PS: Démarrer l'aperçu--><link href="https://espcol401.dit.cb/sites/vincent3/Style%20Library/fr-fr/Themable/foo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!--PE: Terminer l'aperçu-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssLink>-->
```

Until I choosed a particular design the css where linking to foo.css
After I applid a design it linked to foo-6358CA7D.themedcss?ctag=2

So at a point Sharepoint builded cached version of themed css in /sites/mysite/_catalogs/theme/Themed/549F7A23/ but it doesn't copy foo.css into this directory.

How to tell sharepoint it should interpret/cach foo.css in the themed directory ?
(How can I remove a particular design ?)

Comment: did you get this fixed?

Comment: In the short term, you can navigate in SharePoint designer to your built CSS path (eg. `/sites/mysite/_catalogs/theme/Themed/549F7A23/foo-6358CA7D.themedcss`) and paste your CSS over the top. Also I assume the CSS will get rebuilt if you deploy to a new site collection, perhaps try that too.